# Trouble iterating through all files in directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Part of my Bash script's intended function is to accept a directory name and then iterate through every file.

Here is part of my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
# sameln --- remove duplicate copies of files in specified directory

D=$1
cd $D #go to directory specified as default input

fileNum=0 #save file numbers

DIR=".*|*"
for f in $DIR #for every file in the directory
do
    files[$fileNum]=$f #save that file into the array
    fileNum=$((fileNum+1)) #increment the fileNum

    echo aFile
done
```

The echo statement is for testing purposes. I passed as an argument the name of a directory with four regular files, and I expected my output to look like:

aFile

aFile

aFile

aFile

but the echo statement only shows up once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A single operation**

Use `find` for this, it's perfect for it.

```
find <dirname> -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo "{}" \;
```

The flags explained: `maxdepth` defines how deep int he hierarchy you want to look (dirs in dirs in dirs), `type f` defines files, as opposed to `type d` for dirs. And `exec` allows you to process the found file/dir, which is can be accessed through `{}`. You can alternatively pass it to a bash function to perform more tasks.

This simple bash script takes a dir as argument and lists all it's files:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Note that the last line is identical to `find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0`.

**Performing multiple tasks**

Using `find` one can also perform multiple tasks by either piping to `xargs` or `while read`, but I prefer to use a function. An example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function dostuff {
    # echo filename
    echo "filename: $1"
    # remove extension from file
    mv "$1" "${1%.*}"
    # get containing dir of file
    dir="${1%/*}"
    # get filename without containing dirs
    file="${1##*/}"
    # do more stuff like echoing results
    echo "containing dir = $dir and file was called $file"
}; export -f dostuff
# export the function so you can call it in a subshell (important!!!)

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'dostuff "{}"' \;
```

Note that the function needs to be exported, as you can see. This so you can call it in a subshell, which will be opened by executing `bash -c 'dostuff'`. To test it out, I suggest your comment to `mv` command in `dostuff` otherwise you will remove all your extensions haha.

Also note that this **is** safe for weird characters like spaces in filenames so no worries there.

**Closing note**

If you decide to go with the `find` command, which is a great choice, I advise you read up on it because it is a very powerful tool. A simple `man find` will teach you a lot and you will learn a lot of useful options to `find`. You can for instance quit from find once it has found a result, this can be handy to check if dirs contain videos or not for example in a rapid way. It's truly an amazing tool that can be used on various occasions and often you'll be done with a one liner (kinda like `awk`).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how I would pass multiple commands to -exec? If I want to load the contents of the found files into an array, I need multiple lines to do so.

Comment: Or rather than exporting, if it is reusable for more than this script, just save it as a script and call that.

Comment: Indeed, +1 for that remark. It is in fact important to think in this manner, reusing code is always beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating only files below a single directory, you are better off using simple filename/path expansion to avoid certain uncommon filename issues. The following will iterate through all files in a given directory passed as the first argument (default `./`):

```
#!/bin/bash

srchdir="${1:-.}"

for i in "$srchdir"/*; do

    printf " %s\n" "$i"

done
```

If you must iterate below an entire subtree that includes numerous branches, then `find` will likely be your only choice. However, be aware that using `find` or `ls` to populate a `for` loop brings with it the potential for problems with embedded characters such as a `\n` within a filename, etc. See **Why** [**for i in $(find . -type f) # is wrong**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) even though unavoidable at times.

Comment: To be fair that is an improper use of find, in my opinion find is by far the best tool to iterate over files and dirs. `for i in $(find ...)` is definitely never unavoidable.

Comment: There are quite a few double-negatives in there. In the event you have multiple trees of varying depth below a given directory and you need to iterate over the files, what are you saying is the best way to go? I get you are saying finding the files with `find` is the way to go (I agree), but as to iterating over the list found, then what? Call your script via `-exec` or `-execdir`? `xargs`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. Iterate over what list found? - I have never had a problem calling a script through `-exec` and I continue to do it on many occasions.

Comment: The results of the `find` command. Preference, `-exec` or `-execdir`? `xargs`?

Comment: I prefer `-exec` and have seen many use `xargs` but I have never stumbled across a situation where `-exec` didn't do the trick. I'm not saying there are no such situations, I've just never experienced them (almost like a God complex, hahaha).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read the files into the array, then iterate through them:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd $1
files=(*)

for f in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: I like how your answer conserves spaces, much better than `for f in $(ls)`!